# Using a for loop to create a pattern output and how to change the formula to change the pattern

Tags: for-loop

I have to work out how to change code so that the output in the columns or rows I have changes. I have done the following for one that is supposed to print 5 by 5 rows of asterisks with the third row having plus signs instead. It is almost right but something is making the plus signs happen on the 4th row instead of the third. My lecturer said something about it in class being to do with when the value is grabbed, but I can't remember what and it's the weekend so I can't ask him.

I have read a few questions and that gave me a jumping point but I'm still unclear on the following things;

Can you please tell me where I'm going wrong with the third line and fourth line being opposite to how I would like them and give me any pointers on how to change things in specific rows or columns?

Thanks, here is my code;

```
public class OutputB
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int rows = 5; // tells the program how many rows
        int cols = 5; // tells the program how many columns

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)

                if(r != 3)
                { 
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                else 
                { 
                    System.out.print("+");
                }
            System.out.println();
```

Comment: Start counting with your fingers, starting at 0. Arriving at 3 you raise the fourth finger.

Answer (score 0):

You're starting at zero, which means the third increment is actually the fourth. You have two options to fix this. You can either subtract 1 from the desired row number...

```
int rows = 5; // tells the program how many rows
int cols = 5; // tells the program how many columns
int rowOfThePlusSymbol = 3;
...
    if(r != rowOfThePlusSymbol-1)
```

...or you you can start at 1 in your for loop. If you do so, be sure to put <= in your for loop also, so you loop the desired number of times.

```
...
for (int r = 1; r <= rows; r++)
{
    for (int c = 1; c <= cols; c++)
    ...
}
```

I don't encourage using the latter solution because it is normal practice to start at zero when using increments or indexes of lists.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me.